# Python unit test case for mocking directory and generating test files

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, python-unittest, python-unittest.mock

Can we mock test directory and couple of files in python unit test case?

scan.py:

```
import re
from pathlib import Path

class Scan():


    def scan_files(self, dir_path, filter_regex=None):
        for item in Path(dir_path).iterdir():
            if not item.is_symlink():
                if item.is_dir():
                    for child_item in self.scan_files(item, filter_regex=filter_regex):
                        yield child_item
                else:
                    if filter_regex is None:
                        yield item
                    elif filter_regex:
                        if re.match(filter_regex, item.name, re.IGNORECASE):
                            yield item
                    else:
                        pass
```

test_scan.py:

```
import unittest
from mock import patch
from scan import Scan


class TestScan(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self) -> None:
        """Unit Test default 
        """
        pass

    def instantiate_scan_class(self):
        scan = Scan()

        return scan

    def test_scan_files(self):
        dir_path = "/my/test/path"
        
        # Create the UploadWatchService object
        scan = self.instantiate_scan_class()

        result = scan.scan_files(dir_path=dir_path)
        for item in result:
            print(item)




if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

I am running like below

```
python3 -m unittest discover
```

I am getting below error:

```
======================================================================
ERROR: test_scan_files (test_scan.TestScan)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/vcimalap/code/watchservice/src/main/test_scan.py", line 24, in test_scan_files
    for item in result:
  File "/Users/vcimalap/code/watchservice/src/main/scan.py", line 12, in scan_files
    for item in Path(dir_path).iterdir():
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/pathlib.py", line 1160, in iterdir
    for name in self._accessor.listdir(self):
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/my/test/path'
```

Can somebody help me to mock following items, so that I can implement unit test or help me any example unit test for scan.py

```
 1. mocking directory path
 2. Generating few test files
 3. mocking item.is_symlink()
 4. mocking item.is_dir()
```

One way is we can user path.object, I guess that is for method calling output to set.

Comment: I just answered a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73920592). Does this help?

Answer (score 1):

## Create test directories and empty files

Just use `tempfile` (from standard library).

```py
import tempfile

tempfile.TemporaryDirectory().name  
# output: '/tmp/tmpr6ugakay'
```

Since these are file operations, I wouldn't suggest you to mock things. Instead, use `tempfile` to create temporary directories (and files) that will be flushed upon system restart (or according to correspondent system policies).

Similarly to `tempfile.TemporaryDirectory`, there's a `tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile`.

```py
tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(prefix="my_temp_file", suffix=".txt").name  
# output: '/tmp/my_temp_file8aq0dsoo.txt'
```

## Create test files with fake content using `Faker`

For generating fake content for your test files, you could use [Faker](https://faker.readthedocs.io/).

### `Faker` installation

```bash
pip install faker
```

### `Faker` usage

**Imports and initialization**

```py
import tempfile
from pathlib import Path

from faker import Faker

FAKER = Faker()
```

**Create a TXT file with fake content**

```py
file = Path(tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(suffix=".txt").name)
file.write_text(FAKER.text())
```

**Create a PNG file with fake content**

```py
file = Path(tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(suffix=".png").name)
file.write_bytes(FAKER.image())
```

**Create a ZIP file with fake content**

```py
file = Path(tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(suffix=".zip").name)
file.write_bytes(FAKER.zip())
```

Check the [faker docs](https://faker.readthedocs.io/) for more.

## Create test files with fake content using `faker-file`

You could also use [faker-file](https://faker-file.readthedocs.io/), which allows you to have more control of the generated content, supports way more files types (DOCX, PDF and many more), integrates nicely with ORMs (`Django`, `SQLAlchemy`) and [factory_boy](https://factoryboy.readthedocs.io/) and even supports remote storages (such as AWS S3, Azure Cloud Storage and Google Cloud Storage).

### `faker-file` installation

```bash
pip install faker-file[all]
```

### `faker-file` usage

**Imports and initialization**

```py
from faker import Faker

from faker_file.providers.docx_file import DocxFileProvider
from faker_file.providers.pdf_file import PdfFileProvider
from faker_file.providers.txt_file import TxtFileProvider
from faker_file.providers.zip_file import ZipFileProvider
# many more formats supported, check the docs

from faker_file.providers.helpers.inner import create_inner_docx_file

FAKER = Faker()
FAKER.add_provider(DocxFileProvider)
FAKER.add_provider(PdfFileProvider)
FAKER.add_provider(TxtFileProvider)
FAKER.add_provider(ZipFileProvider)
```

**Create a TXT file with randomly generated fake content**

```py
file = FAKER.txt_file()
```

**Create a TXT file with provided content**

```py
file = FAKER.txt_file(content="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet")
```

**Create a PDF file with randomly generated fake content**

```py
file = FAKER.pdf_file()
```

**Create a PDF file with provided content**

```py
file = FAKER.pdf_file(content="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet")
```

**Create a DOCX file with randomly generated fake content**

```py
file = FAKER.docx_file()
```

**Create a DOCX file with provided content**

```py
file = FAKER.docx_file(content="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet")
```

**Create a ZIP file with 3 DOCX files inside with randomly generated fake content**

```py
file = FAKER.zip_file(
    options={
        "count": 3,
        "create_inner_file_func": create_inner_docx_file,
        "create_inner_file_args": {
            "max_nb_chars": 1_024,
        },
    }
)
```

**Create a ZIP file with 1 DOCX files inside with provided content**

```py
file = FAKER.zip_file(
    options={
        "count": 1,
        "create_inner_file_func": create_inner_docx_file,
        "create_inner_file_args": {
            "content": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet",
        },
    }
)
```

Check the [faker-file docs](https://faker-file.readthedocs.io/) for more.